# Permission denied on RHEL 8

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, file-permissions, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm from windows background and almost have no idea how to operate Linux (or AWS). So, I've developed an application and deployed it on AWS. I will summarize what I have done so far and what I have achieved.

- I created an ec2 instance, installed all the required tools and environment for development and production.
- Installed and configured *httpd* daemon, *mariadb* and *phpmyadmin* panel.
- Deployed my application and changed the ownership using the command `chown root:apache ./path/to/directory/*`
- Gave permissions using `chmod -R 775 ./path/to/directory/*`
- Allowed writing permissions for the applications in `semanage` using `semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/path/to/directory(/.*)?"`
- And finally executed this command `restorecon -R /path/to/directory` (not entirely sure what it does, found the permissions guide [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116575/selinux-httpd-write-access-to-a-directory))

After all that I can access my application on web and in proper working condition. But, when I try to FTP my files (using *FileZilla*) it gives me an error saying:

> **Error**: /var/www/Foo/bar.php: open for write: permission denied 
> **Error**: File transfer failed

When I allow permission for other users using `chmod -R 777 ./path/to/directory/*` I can upload files easily. But I read that [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777/20110#20110), `777` isn't always a good idea.

My question is, How can I FTP my files with existing permissions and if I have to change my permissions to `777`, is it okay to do so, if I'm the only user of that instance?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand `chmod -R 777` is not a good idea because 777. Everyone can read, write, and execute your file and your directory, as this allows anyone to add malicious code to your server.

`chmod -R 755` is commonly used by web servers. The owner has all the permissions to read, write, and execute. and other can only read and execute but can not change your file.

Example:

```
chmod -R 755 ./path/to/directory/*
chown -R $USER:$USER ./path/to/directory/*
```

Comment: Yes, but `755` or `775` permissions are not allowing *FileZilla* to FTP. How can I do that without changing my permissions? Please advice.

Comment: Yeah because your account that uses with filezilla is not the owner of that file or directory.

Comment: Ok. This means instead of giving ownership to the `root:apache` I should give ownership to the user which FileZilla is using, means `ec2-user:apache`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah you are right